# How to create Java generic in base class

Tags: java, generics

## Edit

Based on the discussions I've changed my SystemUnderTestFactory implementation to [this](https://gist.github.com/jnericks/4a1bb585daea26fd6b23) (and the [tests](https://gist.github.com/jnericks/7721b1ed177af8d85bc5))

```
public abstract class BaseUnitTesterWithSut<TSut>
{
    protected SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut> SutFactory;

    @Before
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void before()
    {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        SutFactory = new SystemUnderTestFactory<>((Class<TSut>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}

public class SystemTester extends BaseUnitTesterWithSut<System>
{
    @Test
    public void can_subclass_and_test()
    {
        System sut = SutFactory.sut();
        assertThat(sut).isExactlyInstanceOf(System.class);
    }
}
```

## Original Question

Background: I am a C# dev that just started working on a Java 1.8 project and am trying to understand how to accomplish things while working with Generics in Java (to me the Generic implementation and this whole type erasure thing makes them almost pointless).

What I am trying to do is create a base class with a Generic field ("property") that is instantiated in the base class and used in the subclass.

Also, the property I'm creating is an anonymous subclass of an abstract class, so that I can use superclass information to inspect the generic type at run-time using [this "trick"](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) (that was a mouthful)

Is there any way I can accomplish what I want to do below without having to do a method override in the base classes? Am I just thinking about generics in the wrong way while working with Java? Again, I'm used to the C# way to do things, so if there is a Java way to do things that I need to learn/switch to then I would be interested in that as well.

### What I want to accomplish

```
public abstract class BaseUnitTesterWithSut<TSut>
{
    protected SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut> SutFactory;

    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        SutFactory = new SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut>() { };
    }
}

public class SystemTester extends BaseUnitTesterWithSut<System>
{
    @Test
    public void can_subclass_and_test()
    {
        System sut = SutFactory.sut();
        assertThat(sut).isExactlyInstanceOf(System.class);
    }
}
```

### My workaround

```
public class SystemTester // extends BaseUnitTesterWithSut<System>
{
    protected SystemUnderTestFactory<System> SutFactory;

    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        SutFactory = new SystemUnderTestFactory<System>() { }
    }

    @Test
    public void can_subclass_and_test()
    {
        System sut = SutFactory.sut();
        assertThat(sut).isExactlyInstanceOf(System.class);
    }
}
```

### An abbreviated version of the SystemUnderTestFactory

It inspects a class for the constructor with the most dependencies and auto-creates mocks for each dependency, and when you retrieve that object it will create you one using that constructor and the mocks it created.

If you are interested the full implementation can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/jnericks/6567986b1785af171aa1) (and the [tests](https://gist.github.com/jnericks/d2d0125b7ce8b7be4262))

```
public abstract class SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut>
{
    private final Class<TSut> _type;
    private volatile Constructor<?> _ctor;

    private ArrayList _dependencies;
    private TSut _sut;

    public SystemUnderTestFactory()
    {
        ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        _type = (Class<TSut>) superclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        _dependencies = new ArrayList();
        _ctor = getGreediestCtor();

        Class[] parameterTypes = _ctor.getParameterTypes();
        for (Class cls : parameterTypes)
        {
            // Mockito mock
            _dependencies.add(mock(cls));
        }
    }

    public TSut sut()
    {
        return (TSut) _ctor.newInstance(_dependencies.toArray());;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is - you can do new SystemUnderTestFactory<System>() { }; in the base class without a createSutFactory() method.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here - I'm unfamiliar with the c# method, so I can't tell you if you're approaching the problem wrong.  As 6ton pointed out, there's no need for the createSutFactory() method - in fact, you should be able to just initialize SutFactory on the same line as the declaration.

Comment: Could you precise what exactly prevents you from doing the *"What I want to accomplish"* approach? What is the definition of the`SystemUnderTestFactory` class?

Comment: @Aify I understand what you are saying, but I want to prevent from having to do that in every test that I create and have that just be a part of the base class... this is essentially what I'm doing in my workaround

Comment: @Joffrey yea, I think that is basically where my problems stems from, my SystemUnderTestFactory implementation doesn't work when I create it in the base class, i'll update my post with that implementation.

Comment: @JonErickson Wow, that's an interesting way of getting a type parameter at runtime. Usually, the Java way is to actually pass the Class object to the generic class if you really need to instantiate stuff at runtime, but that's a sidenote.

Comment: @6ton I updated my workaround to do exactly what you suggest and it is better than what I had before, but I would like to just have that in a base class so that I don't have to write that code over and over for each test class where I want to use it.

Comment: @JonErickson Also, what do you mean by *"my SystemUnderTestFactory implementation doesn't work"*? Do you get an exception, or an unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @Joffrey I got the idea from [this blog post](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)

Comment: @JonErickson Yeah I saw that in your post already. But I believe you don't need that here, at least in your workaround. In lieu of `new SystemUnderTestFactory<System>()`, you could just use `new SystemUnderTestFactory(System.class)`, hence giving the info at runtime. In your target code, however, this is not possible indeed.

Comment: @Joffrey when `getGenericSuperclass` is called within `SystemUnderTestFactory` constructor it returns `SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut>` instead of `SystemUnderTestFactory<System>` when created in the base class. Maybe I need to look at my `SystemUnderTestFactory` implementation more.

Comment: @JonErickson Ah I see. Yeah, this is because of your implementation of `SystemUnderTestFactory`. In fact, `getGenericSuperclass` works only because the superclass generic information is present at compile time at least, when you write standard stuff like `class A extends GenericClass<MyType>`. But here you're creating an anonymous subclass of a class with an unknown generic type `TSut`, so you don't have that information. And at runtime, everything is erased anyway of course.

Comment: @Joffrey I think I'm stuck with declaring SystemUnderTestFactory within each test class for now, maybe I'll take a look at implementing the factory differently in the future. Thanks for taking some time to explore this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could get the class with reflection from the `BaseUnitTesterWithSut` instead of the `SystemUnderTestFactory`, and then pass it in.

```
abstract class BaseUnitTesterWithSut<TSut>
{
    protected SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut> SutFactory;

    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        ParameterizedType thisType = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        SutFactory = new SystemUnderTestFactory<>((Class<TSut>) thisType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this, this works! and I get the benefit of having SystemUnderTestFactory not being an abstract class and having to do the a subclass trick to create it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused also.  I don't think you are having a problem with basic syntax, but I don't really see the issue either.  Here's some code that compiles.  It doesn't run, and I don't bother to get the type parameter.  I assume you have that bit running.

I don't know how to ask questions without this code to comment on, so I'll risk some reputation and post this.  Let me know which parts you think aren't right/can't be implemented.

I've changed some method and field names to be more Java-like, but aside from that the first two classes are straight from your question.

```
abstract class BaseUnitTesterWithSut<TSut>
{
    protected SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut> sutFactory;

    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        sutFactory = new SystemUnderTestFactory<TSut>() { };
    }
}

class SystemTester extends BaseUnitTesterWithSut<MySystem>
{
    @Test
    public void can_subclass_and_test()
    {
        MySystem sut = sutFactory.getSut();
        assert( sut.getClass() == MySystem.class );
    }
}

class SystemUnderTestFactory<T> {
   T getSut() { return null; }
}

class MySystem {}
@interface Before {}
@interface Test {}
```

It this is suitable, then you could probably get rid of the abstract base class altogether and just load classes with a factory directly.  I think you may have over complicated the issue.

I'm focused on the `getSut()` code.  What do you need to put there?  Where does it actually find these classes?  I think you're focusing on generics but there might be better ways in Java to do this.

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab at this. I'm starting to understand that the issue is coming from my SystemUnderTestFactory and how I'm trying to determine type information within it at runtime, I've updated my question with the full implementation of the SystemUnderTestFactory.

Comment: I think I"m on the same wave length as Joffery;  I think it would be easier to pass the type to a constructor or method instead of trying to glean the type from the generic type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using Java generics in a way that is not exactly their primary purpose.

In fact, in Java, generics are here to ensure type safety at compile-time mostly, and avoid some annoying casting etc. Because of type erasure, they are not really meant to be used at runtime to dynamically create objects.

To create instances at runtime, we usually pass a `Class` object to a constructor or method, to give it runtime type information.

Here it does not seem possible in your target code, but I don't really see what you get from extracting that little code to a base class. I am aware that the following does *not* solve the initial problem you have, but what about writing something like:

```
public class SystemTester {

    private SystemUnderTestFactory<System> sutFactory;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        sutFactory = new SystemUnderTestFactory<System>(System.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void canSubclassAndTest() {
        System sut = sutFactory.sut();
        assertThat(sut).isExactlyInstanceOf(System.class);
    }
}
```

With a slightly simplified version of `SystemUnderTestFactory`'s constructor:

```
public SystemUnderTestFactory(Class<TSut> type) {
    _type = type;

    _dependencies = new ArrayList();
    _ctor = getGreediestCtor();

    Class[] parameterTypes = _ctor.getParameterTypes();
    for (Class cls : parameterTypes)
    {
        // Mockito mock
        _dependencies.add(mock(cls));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I am trying to use the Java generics in a way that they aren't really designed to be used, again I'm a C# guy that is used to having support at run-time for generic type checking. I will probably move to this implementation. I enjoyed our discussion =D

Comment: @JonErickson I'm not familiar with C#, but I guess it has more powerful generics according to what you were trying to do here. And now I'm upset not to find a better solution :) I guess that sometimes we're trying to do things in a too generic way, and in fact simpler is better.

Comment: yeah, in C# I can have a `public class SutFactory<T> { }` and in the constructor I can literally just do `typeof(T)` at run-time to get a `Type` object with all the juicy type information (similar to the `Class<T>` object in java)